Astilectron Launches Additional Window Automatically On System Launch
I am working on a cross-platform (windows + macOS) golang-Electron desktop application. I am using the golang-astilectron library to achieve intercommunication between the backend (golang) and the frontend (electron.js).
Bug Description :

I run my application (golang binary) on macOS.
I restart the system without closing the application before the restart.
Once the system is restarted, the Electron app is run and the following window is displayed :
erroneous window: 
The bug also exists on Windows, but I did not try anything there yet.

I have tried modifying the /vendor/astilectron/main.js (the vendor directory is created by astilectron to contain the needed electron setup to start interacting with golang).
I have tried to add the following lines to that main.js file separately :

app.setLoginItemSettings({ enabled: false });
app.setLoginItemSettings({ openAtLogin: true })

YET, NONE OF WHICH WORKED!!
How to prevent that electron window (process) from automatically launching on system startup (or even at all as this is an unwanted window) ??
